# How to prevent a sub form from disappearing when the record source is empty

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have created a form in Access that dynamically updates the displayed information based on the user's input. There is a sub form that is also updated by changing the record source. However, there are some instances when the record source will be empty. When this occurs the sub form disappears, never to be seen again. I can't even reference the sub form in VB.

I know there is a way to prevent this. I have seen sub forms that display an empty result while still staying visible. However, I can't seem to find the setting that does this.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do all variations of the sub form have the same fields regardless of the record source?

Comment: They have the same type of field, yes. I set the control source of the fields to reflect the changes. It works in all cases except when the query is empty

Comment: possible with a disconnected recordset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a null record set in the super form and/or the sub form. I linked the sub form to a table to ensure there would be some record. Then, I linked the fields that I wanted to filter by to the super form. The super form contained the records I wanted to filter by: kind of like a where clause.

Sorry if the terminology is not correct or the solution is obvious. Access and VBA are fairly new to me.